# How to make the mouse scroll not act on a specific article?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As a sample, I uploaded an HTML site to the test domain. Here is its address: http://test.ooo-pnu.ru/

Full-screen site, consists of three blocks for demonstration. You can scroll them with the mouse wheel or with a swipe on touch devices.

The JS code is responsible for this:

```js
// ------------- VARIABLES ------------- //
var ticking = false;
var isFirefox = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
var isIe = (/MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) || (/Trident.*rv\:11\./i.test(navigator.userAgent));
var scrollSensitivitySetting = 30; //Increase/decrease this number to change sensitivity to trackpad gestures (up = less sensitive; down = more sensitive) 
var slideDurationSetting = 600; //Amount of time for which slide is "locked"
var currentSlideNumber = 0;
var totalSlideNumber = $(".background").length;

// ------------- DETERMINE DELTA/SCROLL DIRECTION ------------- //
function parallaxScroll(evt) {
  if (isFirefox) {
    //Set delta for Firefox
    delta = evt.detail * (-120);
  } else if (isIe) {
    //Set delta for IE
    delta = -evt.deltaY;
  } else {
    //Set delta for all other browsers
    delta = evt.wheelDelta;
  }

  if (ticking != true) {
    if (delta <= -scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      //Down scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== totalSlideNumber - 1) {
        currentSlideNumber++;
        nextItem();
      }
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
    if (delta >= scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      //Up scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== 0) {
        currentSlideNumber--;
      }
      previousItem();
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
  }
}

// ------------- SET TIMEOUT TO TEMPORARILY "LOCK" SLIDES ------------- //
function slideDurationTimeout(slideDuration) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    ticking = false;
  }, slideDuration);
}

// ------------- ADD EVENT LISTENER ------------- //
var mousewheelEvent = isFirefox ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "wheel";
window.addEventListener(mousewheelEvent, _.throttle(parallaxScroll, 60), false);

// ------------- SLIDE MOTION ------------- //
function nextItem() {
  var $previousSlide = $(".background").eq(currentSlideNumber - 1);
  $previousSlide.removeClass("up-scroll").addClass("down-scroll");
}

function previousItem() {
  var $currentSlide = $(".background").eq(currentSlideNumber);
  $currentSlide.removeClass("down-scroll").addClass("up-scroll");
}


// SWIPE MODE Rodichev Vladimir
// at least 100 px are a swipe
// you can use the value relative to screen size: window.innerWidth * .1
const offset = 100;
let xDown, yDown

window.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
  const firstTouch = getTouch(e);

  xDown = firstTouch.clientX;
  yDown = firstTouch.clientY;
});

window.addEventListener('touchend', e => {
  if (!yDown) {
    return;
  }

  const {
    clientY: yUp
  } = getTouch(e);
  const yDiff = yDown - yUp;
  const yDiffAbs = Math.abs(yDown - yUp);

  // at least <offset> are a swipe
  if (Math.max(yDiffAbs) < offset ) {
    return;
  }


    if ( yDiff > 0 ) {
      //Up scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== 0) {
        currentSlideNumber--;
      }
      previousItem();
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    } else {
      //Down scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== totalSlideNumber - 1) {
        currentSlideNumber++;
        nextItem();
      }
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
});

function getTouch (e) {
  return e.changedTouches[0]
}
```

We get down to the last block, in it I inserted test information with a review of the game Headhunter, also for demonstration, the information will scroll horizontally with the mouse wheel too.

The code responsible for the block with horizontal scrolling"

```js
function horizontalScroll(e){
  var that = this;
  that.elementWidth = that.elementWidth || getColumnWidth(that);

  var scrollDirection = ( e.wheelDeltaY )? (0 - e.wheelDeltaY) : ( e.detail),
      actualColumn = Math.round( that.scrollLeft / that.elementWidth),
      targetColumn = (scrollDirection > 0 )? actualColumn + 1 : actualColumn - 1;

  if(scrollElementToColumn( that, targetColumn )) e.preventDefault();

}

function getColumnWidth(that){
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(that, null);
  var columnWidth = parseFloat( style.columnWidth || style.MozColumnWidth || style.webkitColumnWidth );
  var columnGap = parseFloat( style.columnGap || style.MozColumnGap || style.webkitColumnGap );
  return columnWidth + columnGap;
}

function scrollElementToColumn(that, columnIndex){
  that.elementWidth = that.elementWidth || getColumnWidth(that);

  var expectedPlaceToScroll = Math.round(columnIndex * that.elementWidth),
      distanceToScroll = Math.abs( that.scrollLeft - expectedPlaceToScroll ),
      defaultScrollShift = 30,
      savedScrollLeft = that.scrollLeft,
      scrollShift = ( defaultScrollShift < distanceToScroll )? defaultScrollShift : distanceToScroll ;

  if(that.scrollLeft < expectedPlaceToScroll){
    that.scrollLeft = that.scrollLeft + scrollShift;
  }else if(that.scrollLeft > expectedPlaceToScroll){
    that.scrollLeft = that.scrollLeft - scrollShift;
  }

  if(that.scrollLeft !== expectedPlaceToScroll && savedScrollLeft !== that.scrollLeft ){
    that.actuallyMoving = setTimeout( function(){scrollElementToColumn( that, columnIndex )}, 10);
    return true;
  }

  if( that.actuallyMoving ) clearTimeout(that.actuallyMoving);
  return false;
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('mario');
  var i;
  for(i = 0, nb = elems.length; i < nb; i++){
    if (elems[i].addEventListener) {
      elems[i].addEventListener("mousewheel", horizontalScroll, false);// IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
      elems[i].addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", horizontalScroll, false);// Firefox
    } else elems[i].attachEvent("onmousewheel", horizontalScroll);// IE 6/7/8
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', function(e){
    console.log('resizing, i saw you !');
    for(i = 0, nb = elems.length; i < nb; i++){
      elems[i].elementWidth = getColumnWidth(elems[i]);
    }
  });
});
```

article in which content scrolls horizontally:

```html
<article class="mario">
```

How to make the screen scrolling at the same time when the mouse wheel is scrolling on the content in the very last block? In this case, you need a solution so that you can wind the screen too. So far, I have an idea such that the scrolling screen does not work on the article when the cursor is pointed, only the content scrolling works, we move the cursor away from the article - then the scrolling of the screens works again.

Changes made in index.js:

```
// ------------- VARIABLES ------------- //
var isHorizontal = false;
var ticking = false;
var isFirefox = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
var isIe = (/MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) || (/Trident.*rv\:11\./i.test(navigator.userAgent));
var scrollSensitivitySetting = 30; //Increase/decrease this number to change sensitivity to trackpad gestures (up = less sensitive; down = more sensitive) 
var slideDurationSetting = 600; //Amount of time for which slide is "locked"
var currentSlideNumber = 0;
var totalSlideNumber = $(".background").length;

// ------------- DETERMINE DELTA/SCROLL DIRECTION ------------- //
function parallaxScroll(evt) {
  if(isHorisontal) {
    isHorisontal = false;
    return;
  }
  if (isFirefox) {
    //Set delta for Firefox
    delta = evt.detail * (-120);
  } else if (isIe) {
    //Set delta for IE
    delta = -evt.deltaY;
  } else {
    //Set delta for all other browsers
    delta = evt.wheelDelta;
  }

  if (ticking != true) {
    if (delta <= -scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      //Down scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== totalSlideNumber - 1) {
        currentSlideNumber++;
        nextItem();
      }
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
    if (delta >= scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      //Up scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== 0) {
        currentSlideNumber--;
      }
      previousItem();
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
  }
}

// ------------- SET TIMEOUT TO TEMPORARILY "LOCK" SLIDES ------------- //
function slideDurationTimeout(slideDuration) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    ticking = false;
  }, slideDuration);
}

// ------------- ADD EVENT LISTENER ------------- //
var mousewheelEvent = isFirefox ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "wheel";
window.addEventListener(mousewheelEvent, _.throttle(parallaxScroll, 60), false);

// ------------- SLIDE MOTION ------------- //
function nextItem() {
  var $previousSlide = $(".background").eq(currentSlideNumber - 1);
  $previousSlide.removeClass("up-scroll").addClass("down-scroll");
}

function previousItem() {
  var $currentSlide = $(".background").eq(currentSlideNumber);
  $currentSlide.removeClass("down-scroll").addClass("up-scroll");
}


// SWIPE MODE Rodichev Vladimir
// at least 100 px are a swipe
// you can use the value relative to screen size: window.innerWidth * .1
const offset = 100;
let xDown, yDown

window.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
  const firstTouch = getTouch(e);

  xDown = firstTouch.clientX;
  yDown = firstTouch.clientY;
});

window.addEventListener('touchend', e => {
  if (!yDown) {
    return;
  }

  const {
    clientY: yUp
  } = getTouch(e);
  const yDiff = yDown - yUp;
  const yDiffAbs = Math.abs(yDown - yUp);

  // at least <offset> are a swipe
  if (Math.max(yDiffAbs) < offset ) {
    return;
  }


    if ( yDiff > 0 ) {
      //Up scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== 0) {
        currentSlideNumber--;
      }
      previousItem();
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    } else {
      //Down scroll
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== totalSlideNumber - 1) {
        currentSlideNumber++;
        nextItem();
      }
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
});

function getTouch (e) {
  return e.changedTouches[0]
}
```

Changes made in horizontalscroll.js:

```
function horizontalScroll(e){
  isHorisontal = true;
  var that = this;
  that.elementWidth = that.elementWidth || getColumnWidth(that);

  var scrollDirection = ( e.wheelDeltaY )? (0 - e.wheelDeltaY) : ( e.detail),
      actualColumn = Math.round( that.scrollLeft / that.elementWidth),
      targetColumn = (scrollDirection > 0 )? actualColumn + 1 : actualColumn - 1;

  if(scrollElementToColumn( that, targetColumn )) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
  } else {
    isHorisontal = false;
  }

}

function getColumnWidth(that){
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(that, null);
  var columnWidth = parseFloat( style.columnWidth || style.MozColumnWidth || style.webkitColumnWidth );
  var columnGap = parseFloat( style.columnGap || style.MozColumnGap || style.webkitColumnGap );
  return columnWidth + columnGap;
}

function scrollElementToColumn(that, columnIndex){
  that.elementWidth = that.elementWidth || getColumnWidth(that);

  var expectedPlaceToScroll = Math.round(columnIndex * that.elementWidth),
      distanceToScroll = Math.abs( that.scrollLeft - expectedPlaceToScroll ),
      defaultScrollShift = 30,
      savedScrollLeft = that.scrollLeft,
      scrollShift = ( defaultScrollShift < distanceToScroll )? defaultScrollShift : distanceToScroll ;

  if(that.scrollLeft < expectedPlaceToScroll){
    that.scrollLeft = that.scrollLeft + scrollShift;
  }else if(that.scrollLeft > expectedPlaceToScroll){
    that.scrollLeft = that.scrollLeft - scrollShift;
  }

  if(that.scrollLeft !== expectedPlaceToScroll && savedScrollLeft !== that.scrollLeft ){
    that.actuallyMoving = setTimeout( function(){scrollElementToColumn( that, columnIndex )}, 10);
    return true;
  }

  if( that.actuallyMoving ) clearTimeout(that.actuallyMoving);
  return false;
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('mario');
  var i;
  for(i = 0, nb = elems.length; i < nb; i++){
    if (elems[i].addEventListener) {
      elems[i].addEventListener("mousewheel", horizontalScroll, false);// IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
      elems[i].addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", horizontalScroll, false);// Firefox
    } else elems[i].attachEvent("onmousewheel", horizontalScroll);// IE 6/7/8
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', function(e){
    console.log('resizing, i saw you !');
    for(i = 0, nb = elems.length; i < nb; i++){
      elems[i].elementWidth = getColumnWidth(elems[i]);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Did I understand correctly: you want screen scrolling down until your block with the horizontal scrolling, then scroll right until the last slide of the horizontal block, then scroll down again if any other blocks are present. When scrolling up, the sequence should be reversed: scroll-up, scroll-left, scroll-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your [test website](http://test.ooo-pnu.ru/) you could do the following adjustments:

**index.js:**

```
var isHorizontal = false; //Global variable

function parallaxScroll(evt) {
  if(isHorizontal) {
    isHorizontal = false;
    return;
  }
```

**horisontalscroll.js:**

```
function horizontalScroll(e){
  isHorizontal = true;    

  // skipped

  if(scrollElementToColumn( that, targetColumn )) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
  } else {
    isHorizontal = false;
  }
```

Comment: It works. But! At the very beginning it is impossible to scroll the blocks down.
Is it possible to somehow make a working version?

Comment: Could you please update your demo website with changes. `var isHorizontal = false` should cover very beginning.

Comment: I made it. update demo website. Description of the change in the files updated in the comments to the question. Please help Sergey.

Comment: My bad. You could have caught it by looking, for example, at the DevTools console in Chrome. There is a typo: isHori**z**ontal in globals and isHori**s**ontal everywhere. Let's make it `isHorizontal` - I will update my answers.